# Buildroot is not compiling device tree with -@ option (dtc)

Tags: compilation, overlay, buildroot, device-tree

I'm using Buildroot 2022.11 to create images for the Radxa Zero. I used [this blog](https://bootlin.com/blog/using-device-tree-overlays-example-on-beaglebone-boards/) to apply device tree overlays. It worked as expected when I used a precompiled device tree from a DietPi OS. I will need a device tree overlay for `ttyAML0` and `PWM_C` to activate these devices.

However, while trying to apply this method Buildroot is not compiling the device tree with -@ option. Even if the option `BR2_LINUX_KERNEL_DTB_OVERLAY_SUPPORT=y` is set. This results in the error in U-Boot when using `fdt apply ${dto_addr}`

```
failed on fdt_overlay_apply(): FDT_ERR_BADSTRUCTURE
base fdt does did not have a /__symbols__ node
make sure you've compiled with -@`
```

It obviously seems that the option `BR2_LINUX_KERNEL_DTB_OVERLAY_SUPPORT` is not set when compiling DT with Buildroot. I even tried `make clean` and rebuild the whole image.

Comment: Your sentence "It obviously seems that the option BR2_LINUX_KERNEL_DTB_OVERLAY_SUPPORT is not set when compiling with DT with Buildroot. I even tried make clean and rebuild the whole image." is really unclear. Definitely, when BR2_LINUX_KERNEL_DTB_OVERLAY_SUPPORT=y, Buildroot passes DTC_FLAGS=-@ to the kernel build process.

Comment: With `cat .config | grep BR2_LINUX_KERNEL_DTB_OVERLAY_SUPPORT` I can confirm that the option is set. Then running `make`. However when using the device tree from the output folder `meson-g12a-radxa-zero.dtb`. I get the error described in the post, hence concluding the option is not set or applied. Is there a way to check if the .dtb is compiled with -@?

Comment: To verify that a DT and DTO were compiled with the -@ option you can use the `fdtdump` tool that is in the dtc package. Using like `fdtdump <DT or DTO> | grep magic`. For now I assume if the output has `// magic:  0xd00dfeed`, it was compiled with the -@ option. Strange is that `//` is indicating its commented out. But the .dtb has no such comment